# How to: Provide component with innerBlocks to Wordpress Gutenberg's save function?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

What I have:

- I have a UI-kit written as React library and tailwind.
- Each element in this UI-kit uses a functional approach and hooks.
- Every component has logic that depends on props (which I convert to attributes).

and the problem is that I cannot reuse these components inside the save function of Gutenberg due to the constraints of this function. (save function can't use components/function that has side effects like hooks)

so, in the first case where I've needed to just re-use my component I used this approach:

```
export default function save({attributes}) {
     const {text , variant} = attributes;
     return (
         <> 
            {parseHTML(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                <Button variant={variant}>
                    <RichText.Content value={text}/>
                </Button>
            ))}
         </>
     );
 }
```

1. Convert component and its subcomponents to string using react-dom/server
2. Convert that string into a single react component using [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)
3. Provide this component to save function

And it worked perfectly so far I didn't need to use InnerBlocks for nested blocks:

```
const save = ({attributes})  => {
    return (
        <div>
            {parseHTML(
                ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                    <Wrapper>
                        <InnerBlocks.Content/> 
                    </Wrapper>
                )
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and the error:

```
index.js:5130 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Component(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
at validateRenderResult (index.js:5130)
at processChild (index.js:5254)
at resolve (index.js:5150)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (index.js:5633)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (index.js:5570)
at Object.renderToString (index.js:6178)
at save (index.js:7448)
at getSaveElement (blocks.js:9166)
at getSaveContent (blocks.js:9213)
at addParsedDifference (block-editor.js:14707)
```